# copy one2many field through copy function in odoo

Tags: function, copy, duplicates, odoo

I am making duplicate of an invoice in Odoo. I have made a new one2many field in the invoice line. When I make a duplicate invoice, the one2many field in the invoice line does not get duplicated. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get one2many field duplicated because it's not stored in the model it self, but it's generated when requesting.

Lines are many2one to invoice, so the id of invoice is set in each line, if you duplicate the invoice you can not duplicate lines two by same function, nether changing invoice_id in lines.

So it's a normal behavior.